# dcm4che - tag is a "8 byte integer"?

Tags: java, int, dcm4che

I am a dcm4che newbie I am referring to [the javadoc of dcm4che2 api](http://www.dcm4che.org/docs/dcm4che2-apidocs/)

Pardon if my question is very basic 
I Trying to create a DICOM object "org.dcm4che2.data.DicomObject" from a file.

Most of the member functions of DicomObject that work with DICOM tag expect the tag value to be specified as "ggggeeee" , where gggg is four digit group id and eeee is four digit element id.

The dcm4j documentation refers to tag value as "tag - (group, element) as 8 byte integer: ggggeeee."  - and the data type expected is int

I suppose this is simply a misnomer ( sadly though it is consistently followed in api documentation all across )

java "int" datatype can hold only four bytes isn't it?
So we rather need to provide a 8 digit number as opposed to 8 bytes isnt it.

for example if I am specifying  DICOM tag transfer syntax UID - which is group 2 tag 10 then I should be good passing a value as follows isn't it?

```
 int  dicomTagXferSyntaxUid=0x00020010;
```

While it is so obvious , I wonder why dcm4che documentation refers to it consistently as "8 byte integer" ... what am I missing ?

Comments welcome

Yogesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be a typo, since that "8 byte integer" is used to describe method parameters of `int` type, which is only 4 bytes.

It makes sense that what was intended, as you say yourself, was "8 digit integer".

Comment: Eran, thanks for prompt response. Yid you ever come across any working samples of dcm4che ? It will be gr8 if you can point me to those

Comment: @YogeshDevi No, I just looked at the Javadoc. You can't pass an 8 byte integer (there's no such thing, but you can't pass a long either) to a method whose signature has an int argument.

Comment: DICOM standard says a tag is "An ordered pair of 16-bit unsigned integers representing the Group Number followed by Element Number." So, just confirming that the documentation probably means 8 digit.

Answer (score 0):

The statement in the DCM4CHE documentation is correct. A quick glance at the Javadoc for the Tag class shows this:

org.dcm4che2.data 
Class Tag

java.lang.Object
  extended by org.dcm4che2.data.Tag

```
public class Tag
extends java.lang.Object
```

Provides tag constants.

Field Summary

```
static int  _3DRenderingType 
      (0072,0520) VR=CS, VM=1-n 3D Rendering Type
static int  AbsoluteChannelDisplayScale 
      (003A,0248) VR=FL, VM=1 Absolute Channel Display Scale
.
.
.
```

The values are clearly of type int, which in Java are 32-bit or 4 bytes, exactly as per the DCM4CHE documentation. I think that your misunderstanding is that you have assumed each of the g's and e's in the Tag representation (gggg,eeee) is a byte. It is not; rather it's a hex digit, so that each pair ee represents a byte.